# How do you run a PHP script without loading a page

Tags: php, cron

I need something to run a PHP script without loading the page, a script maybe? Cause my PHP script is on a FTP thingy that doesn't allow me to open any program, only to put my CMS there. I found something called Cron, can someone explain what is it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In this site you're expected to ask specific programming questions, read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) if unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused what you mean? You have a PHP script but you don't want it to be executing on a webpage? That sounds like a cron job.

Essentially a Cron Job allows you to run a PHP script with certain rules. Be it at certain times of the day etc etc.

Try reading this:

http://service.futurequest.net/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/23

Comment: I heard that Cron is for Linux or something? I'm Window based, I'm creating this website that needs a running timer even tho the PHP page isn't laoded.In another word, Someone will load the page, a timer will be called(Cron) and in some time if the user doesn't press a button, some thing(Cron) will run a PHP script to update my MYSQL database. Any idea what can do that?

Comment: I think you are over complicating things, Go back a few steps and Write down EVERYTHING you need to do in order. Including the small details. From here, tackle it one step at a time :)

Answer (score 0):

Cron is a service that executes commands that you define at certain times of the day, certain days of the week, month, year etc. A crontab is used to execute repeated tasks such as log cleanup, building stats etc.

If you need to execute a particular script on the server, depending on how often you want to execute it, you want add a line to your list of crontabs.

Take a look at this [cron introduction](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) to learn how to specify what you insert.

Judging by your tone of your question though, maybe it would be better for someone you know to help you as it server management can become quite tricky at times!

Comment: Is Cron a web script or a program? Cause I can't run any program on this free FTP website that I have

Comment: You need to contact your provider and ask them about cron. There's no such thing as a "FTP website". You may log in to an ftp account to upload files to a particular place that are accessible publicly (a website) or not. As for details about what cron is, you can easily google about it. Stack overflow is for specific questions on how to do something particular, not general, "what is" questions. As for your question in your comment to phpfreak12, you need javascript. It's nothing to do with cron. Now that you've figured out your question, you should find your answer easily!